# Android автообновление приложения

Tags: android, обновления

Подскажите каким образом реализовать автообновление приложение , при его запуске.

Comment: Не ленитесь и поясните что вы имеете ввиду, а то ничего непонятно

Comment: Размещаете приложение в google play и он сам проследит за автообновлением. Ваша задача размещать туда новые версии

Comment: Ситауия пользователь скачал приложениес , но в гугл плее к него отключено автообновление, как реализовать при запуске приложения его обновление до послденей версии , если таковая имеется.

Comment: Если пользователь отключил автообновление, значит оно его не интересует. Не надо навязываться со своими услугами, такой "сервис" скорее приведет к удалению приложения, чем к благодарности

Comment: Это не решение моей задачи

Comment: @Александр, смотрите всю известную нам инфу в ответе у вопроса-дубликата

Comment: да, не решение. Поэтому в комментарии, а не в ответе, просто предупреждение, что пользователь может быть вовсе не рад вашей инициативе.

Comment: Да в этом вы правы